# RecoverySystem.installPackage java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-source, ota, android-rom

I'm playing with AOSP, and trying to apply OTA package

1). I built AOSP for Google Pixel and installed it

2). I created simple app, which downloads OTA package, and trying to apply it
(It's based on this article: http://jhshi.me/2013/12/13/how-to-apply-downloaded-ota-package/index.html)

I'm calling
`RecoverySystem.installPackage(getContext(), file);`, and it gets me

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.os.IRecoverySystem.setupBcb(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at android.os.RecoverySystem.setupBcb(RecoverySystem.java:895)
    at android.os.RecoverySystem.installPackage(RecoverySystem.java:496)
    at android.os.RecoverySystem.installPackage(RecoverySystem.java:421)
```

Can anyone point me how to fix it please?

Comment: I'm noticing the same thing, did you find a resolution?

Comment: @Alex, yes, but I forget how I solved it. As I remember, there was a problem with permissions. You have to grant permission:
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT" />`
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECOVERY" />`
The last one, can be granted to system apps only, as I remember

Comment: BTW, you can check this useful example: https://github.com/CopperheadOS/platform_packages_apps_Updater
This is an internal updater implementation for CopperheadOS

Comment: It was a  permissions problem for me.  If you have a priv-app installed on your device and add a permission then reinstall the app, it won't pick up the new permission.  You have to remove the old app and copy the apk over to the priv-app folder and then reinstall from there to get the new permission Thanks for pointing me to the CopperheadOS version @Alexander

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see, your error comes from this piece of code:

In RecoverySystem.java:

```
RecoverySystem rs = (RecoverySystem) context.getSystemService(
                Context.RECOVERY_SERVICE);
if (!rs.setupBcb(command)) {
    throw new IOException("Setup BCB failed");
}
```

....

```
/**
 * Talks to RecoverySystemService via Binder to set up the BCB.
 */
private boolean setupBcb(String command) {
    try {
        return mService.setupBcb(command);
    } catch (RemoteException unused) {
    }
    return false;
}
```

In the first piece of code, the if evaluation, your error is `rs` has it's `mService` member as `null`. Which is used in the ''setupBcb` method.
So it looks like the context you are using does NOT have Context.RECOVERY_SERVICE reachable somehow.

Are you using activity context? I would git Application Context a try.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread but I had the exact same issue on Android 7.1 even after setting the required permissions and putting the apk file in /system/app/myapp. I solved it by adding this line to the AndroidManifest.xml.

> android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"

And my manifest file is like this -

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.myapp"
    android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
```